# Certificate error when doing OSM query

Tags: r

I would like to do an OSM query

```
library(osmdata)
q <- opq(bbox = 'greater london uk') %>%
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = 'motorway')
```

But I got this error message:

```
! Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates: [nominatim.openstreetmap.org] SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that the SSL certificate for the nominatim.openstreetmap.org server has expired, and cannot be authenticated by the client system. This can cause issues with connecting to the server and accessing the data.

To fix this issue, you can try updating the SSL certificates on your system. Depending on your operating system and the tools you are using, this may involve updating the root certificate authorities, or installing a new certificate from the OpenStreetMap website.

Alternatively, you can try using a different server for the OSM data, such as overpass-api.de, which may have a valid SSL certificate. You can specify the server to use in the 'server' argument of the 'opq' function, like this:

```
q <- opq(bbox = 'greater london uk', server = 'overpass-api.de') %>%
add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = 'motorway') %>%
osmdata_download()
```

This should allow you to connect to the server and download the data, even if the SSL certificate has expired on the nominatim server.

Comment: Error in osmdata_download(.) : could not find function "osmdata_download" , I get this error message

Comment: Make sure you have imported the osmdata library

Comment: I did it, and it didn't work

Comment: @Viv: Are you sure about this? `osmdata::opq()` does not seem to have a `server` attribute. Moreover, SSL certificate of nominatim.openstreetmap.org seems to expire on March 8th, 2023 (checked via browser) and should therefore be valid right now.

Comment: @dmflk  but why it doesn't work on my computer?

Comment: i try on another computer and it works